# directed broadcast ping on overlapping subnets

Tags: subnet, ip-address, ping, directed-broadcast

I have a router with 2 hosts connected to it.

R: 192.168.0.1/24
host 1: 192.168.0.9/28
host 2: 192.168.0.15/24

Host 1's directed broadcast IP is the same as host 2, so what happens if host 1 pings 192.168.0.15 - is the ping successful, with a reply from host 2?  It is not clear to me if host 1 will be able to ping host 2 via the router, or if the ping will not work until host 1's subnet is fixed.

Comment: Traffic on the same network does not pass through a router, it is sent directly from host to host.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Host 1 is the one that needs to be fixed. Everyone else is /24)

Host 1 will send a layer-2 broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) as 0.15 is not a unicast host. (it won't ARP for it) Host 2 *may* answer, or it *may* drop the broadcast ICMP echo request. In either case, host 2 will see it.

Comment: Ah, typo, I fixed it.  Thank you!  What determines if host 2 answers?